# Para que serve o Zip de Enumerable em .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Estava fazendo um código para combinar duas listas, e procurando melhorar descobri o método [`Zip`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.8) da interface `IEnumerable`.

A princípio pensei que era algum algoritmo para "zipar" uma lista/array/etc., mas vi que ele faz ema combinação dos elementos de duas listas enumeráveis.

Como não serviu para o que eu precisava fui procurar outra solução, mas me pareceu interessante, e gostaria de saber mais sobre, e talvez ajude outras pessoas aqui.

Exemplo do link da documentação:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
string[] words = { "one", "two", "three" };

var numbersAndWords = numbers.Zip(words, (first, second) => first + " " + second);
```

Daí a dúvida, para que exatamente serve o `.Zip`?

Algum exemplo de uma utilidade prática?

Comment: Bom dia Ricardo, beleza? Uma boa explicação com exemplos encontrei nesse site aqui. Da uma olhadinha: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.8 valeuu!!

Comment: @ULISSESJOSEDOSSANTOSFILHO esse é exatamente o link que está na minha pergunta :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A confusão com compactação vem do fato de alguns mecanismos de compactação usarem o termo para dizer que espremem algo, o que não deixa de ser uma função do *zipper* já que ele ajusta algo folgado para ficar mais justo, menor. Mas a ação em si é só pegar duas partes e ir sincronizando até que ela vire uma coisa só, não significa que fica menor de fato.

## O que é um *zipper*?

É um mecanismo que junta duas partes fazendo ela ficar como se fosse uma.

[image: Zipper de roupa]

O que ele faz de fato é apenas pegar o dado de um lado e juntar com o dado de outro lado de alguma forma especificada, exatamente como ocorre em um *zipper*, cada gominho de um lado vai encaixando com o gominho do outro lado, conforme mostra o exemplo da pergunta.

A criatividade pode ser grande em o que fazer com os dados provenientes das duas sequências de dados enumeráveis, o que importa é apenas ter essas sequências e um algoritmo que diga que resultado gerar, é uma forma de emparceiramento.

## Exemplos

Poderia pegar dois valores e montar tuplas ou tipos de dados juntos.

Poderia casar estados que estão em um lado e as capitais que estão em outro e criar um objeto que contenha as duas informações. Poderia ser a lista completa das unidades existentes ou poderia ser uma lista de dados individuais de alguma coisa que essa informação faça sentido, mas que estão separados em objetos diferentes.

Tem determinado tipo de banco de dados NoSQL que os dados de uma mesma entidade ficam separados, é um uso errado da tecnologia, mas poderia construir a entidade com um `Zip()` que junta os dados vindos separadamente.

Pode só criar um objeto com uma forma sequencial, então de um lado terá um enumerador gerado na hora sequencial de 1 até o tamanho total de itens, do outro lado com os dados da outra sequência, só para os objetos terem uma numeração explícita, quem sabe seria um `id`.

Pode criar valores totais pegando de um lado a quantidade e de outro o valor unitário, apenas fazendo uma multiplicação simples.

A enumeração pode vir de qualquer lugar, pode ser até uma função que vai pegando um campo dos itens de uma coleção de um lado e outro campo do mesmo objeto da coleção. É muito comum ele ser usado composto com outros métodos, como é o LINQ.

Pode criar um JSON onde você junta os nomes descritores dos membros do JSON com os dados vindos de outro lugar, algo assim:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var header = new string[2] { "nome", "endereco" };
        var joao = new string[2] { "joão", "rua santa cruz, 28" };
        var json = header.Zip(joao, (header, data) => "\"" + header + "\" : \"" + data + "\"");
        foreach (var item in json) WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/IRqstY). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0grMGY). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/Zip.cs).

Não montei o JSON todo, até porque não para isso teria que fazer um *array* bidimensional, ou então ter uma função na coleção que cria a coleção de dados partindo do objeto que seria provável em código real para produzir a lista de campos, apenas para passar a ideia de uso.

Claro que as combinações devem ser simples, se tiver que fazer um algoritmo complexo começa perder sua validade, não dá para achar uma informação que case bem para juntar com outro, pense nos *gominhos*.

Ajuda entender: [Método Zip() do .NET em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/436807/101).

[Veja o fonte do método](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Zip.cs,3ae08ae036c4ab24) como é simples.

Comment: *"É um mecanismo que junta duas partes fazendo ela ficar com se fosse uma"* nossa, não tinha pensado nisso, faz todo sentido! ;)

Answer (score 6):

Basicamente ele te permite combinar duas listas, através de uma função que você escreve de acordo com a sua necessidade.

[Esse post](http://jesseliberty.com/2011/06/13/the-linq-zip-operator/) tem um exemplo legal, onde ele combina a lista de siglas dos estados com uma lista de nomes de estado. Pensando no cenário do Brasil, poderíamos ter uma lista de CEP e combinar com os nomes das ruas.

Abaixo segue o trecho do código.

```
string[] codes = { "AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA" };
string[] states = 
{
   "Alabama", 
   "Alaska", 
   "Arizona", 
   "Arkansas", 
   "California" 
};

var CodesWithStates = 
   codes.Zip(
      states, 
      (code, state) => code + ": " + state);

foreach ( var item in CodesWithStates )
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

**A saída será:**

> AL: Alabama
>   AK: Alasca
>   AZ: Arizona
>   AR: Arkansas
>   CA: Califórnia

Comment: Rafael, transcreve um pedaço do código desse link na tua respostas para não ficar só o link, que um dia pode fica fora do ar e perder o sentido da resposta ;)

Comment: show @RicardoPontual, obrigado pela dica!